# How do you change the subject on emails sent to DocuSign sender

Tags: docusignapi

I want the email subject to have our client's name appended to it but don't want it on the email that goes to the client.  I've checked DocuSign's default-email-formats PDF for modifying the email resource file but didn't find anything there.  What tag in the resource file controls the email subject?

David

Comment: That's a very odd request, you want to use the email subject to store data, but you don't want the email recipient to see the subject line.  Doesn't really make sense.  What are you trying to accomplish overall?  There's probably a better place to store whatever info you're trying to store, such as an envelope custom field.  Those are fields at the envelope level that you can setup and use to hold whatever info you want.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear how you are sending the emails or if the client is a CC on the email or the recipient.

However if the client is a CC then you can set different email messages and subjects on the template by clicking on the link "Customize email and signing language for each recipient" on the template under *Email Message*.

Alternatively if using the API when creating the envelope the subject can be set as part of the recipients parameters using the emailNotifications property, JSON from API

```
"emailNotification"{
    "emailBody":"email text",
    "emailSubject":"Subject text",
    "supportedLanguage":"en",
},
```